# when i easy_install greenlet i got "error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 "

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, easy-install

when i easy_install greenlet(also eventlet) as the documents says in ubuntu 10.04 i got the error above.
is there anyone know why?
Expect your help!

And I have install build-essential

As I canot take the format right here, so I paste the message printed out there http://sugelawa.appspot.com/?p=35001

Thank u very much!

Comment: you need to paste more of what was returned, the status code 1 just indicates that it was not successful. Also, please put it in your post within the code tags, not all in the title.

Comment: Are you shure you have gcc & friends installed? (otherwise try 'apt-get install build-essential')

Comment: I'v fixed this problem by 'apt-get install python2.6-dev'
as i found the error message 'Python.h: No such file or directory'

Comment: Add 'python-all-dev' too, see restating as an answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(*Warning: Ubuntu specific answer. Somewhat applicable to Debian, to but I don't have the details in my head right now*) To use `easy_install` to install modules that contain C extensions (like `greenlet`), you need a complete development stack installed on your system. For a basic install, the means `build-essential` for the C part and `python-all-dev` for the Python part (that's where `Python.h` lives).

Add an 'ubuntu' tag to the question for clarity (don't have sufficient reputation myself as of now)

Comment: Thanks this package I was missing: python-all-dev after installing this it finished installing